# Que siginifica este regex?

Tags: java, regex

```
 Pattern.compile("J.*\\d[0-35-9]-\\d\\d-\\d\\d");
```

Bien, compilar en un pattern, pero concretamente esto \d[0-35-9] que quiere decir?. Un dígito entre que rango¿ 0 y 9, 0 y 35, 0 y 26?
O quizá entre 0 y 3 y entre 5 y 9? que parece lo más lógico...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sección `\d[0-35-9]` Quiere decir:

- `\d` Un dígito cualquiera
- `[0-35-9]` Otro dígito, que puede estar en el intervalo [0-3] o bien en el intervalo [5-9]

Es lo mismo que si pones `[A-Za-z]`: significa una letra en el rango de las mayúsculas o una letra en el rango de las minúsculas. Y tampoco es que se pueda otra cosa, porque no existe la letra `Za` como para que haya confusión.

En definitiva, el 3 y el 5 pertenecen a rangos distintos dentro del `or`.

Por tanto, `[0-35-9]` es equivalente a `[0-3]|[5-9]`.

Answer (score 3):

En realidad, son **dos** dígitos, el último no es un 4.

El sitio web 'Regex101' explica esto: https://regex101.com/r/u3xKCa/1/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]